# How to organize Laravel ORM for relationships table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two table Users and Relationships. The table Relationships contains next fields:

```
id | user_one_id (fk to users) | user_two_id (fk to users) | status | action_user_id
```

The status field can be one of 4 values. 0 - pending, 1 - accepted, 2 - rejected, 3 - blocked.

Action user is those user who created or updated request. For example, user with id 1 want to be a friend with user with id 2. action_user_id will 1.

I can't organize relationships in my User model.

For example my method friends

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'relationships', 'id', 'user_one_id')
                ->orWhere('user_two_id', $this->id);
}
```

creates next sql query:

```
select * from "users" inner join "relationships" on "users"."id" = "relationships"."user_one_id" where "relationships"."user_one_id" = ? or "user_two_id" = ?
```

but I understand that it is not i need.

What i need? I need 3 methods "friends", "requested" and "blackList".

The "friends" method must return all friends of current user. The "requested" method must return all friend requests to current user. And the "blackList" must return all users who are in the blocked status of current user.

Comment: In the relationship table, is it like user with user_one_id sent request to user with user_two_id? As with this `The "requested" method must return all friend requests to current user.` it means get all user_two_id ids where user_one_id is of given user and status is requested? Also, it would be great if you could explain what all these relations are in terms of user_one_id, user_two_id.

Comment: user_one_id and user_two_id are just foreign keys to users table. As for "requested" I mean get all request from other users who want to be a friend.

Comment: Let's say this is an entry from relationships table    user_one_id `1`, user_two_id `6`, status `requested`. Now what does this mean, 1 sent request to 6, or 6 sent request to 1 ?

Comment: I forgot describe one field from relationships database which is called action_user_id. I correct it.

Comment: And let's say, 1 sends request to 6, then action_id will be 1, how do you assign 1,6 to the user_one_id, user_two_id. I mean should you assign 1 to user_one_id or user_two_id?

Comment: records in database do not duplicated. There is a unique key user_one_id_user_two_id. The logic is before insert record I use smaller id for user_one_id. Therefore there are no two recorde 1-6 and 6-1

Answer (score 0):

Try using a where clause, based on the status to retrieve the particular data. I recreated the problem in a fresh laravel install, and I used the user class and a relationships table to reffer to two users in a relationship

```php
//Model User: $user->friends gets the list of friends of the user
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'relationships','friend_2','friend_1')->where('friendship_status','friends');
    }
```

At the blade.php view:

```php
@foreach(\App\User::all() as $user)
   <h5>{{$user->name}}</h5>
   @foreach($user->friends as $friends)
       <div>
            <small>Is friends with {{$friends->name}}</small>
       </div>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[image: As you can see, the relationship is complete]

Relationships table migration:

```php
Schema::create('relationships', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('friend_1');
            $table->unsignedbigInteger('friend_2');
            $table->string('friendship_status')->default('request pending');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Manually added relationships:

[image]

Comment: I think those join which will appear in query will return incorrect results

Comment: How exactly?. Do you have a test to check the output of these functions?

Comment: You might need to add more logic behind the relationships and retrieve the info without the orWhere, separate like: _user1_  hasblocked _user2_, user2_ isBlockedBy _user1, then make pairs of functions like: ```function blockedBy() and function blocked()```

Comment: for example. I have a user with ID 1. I created two new users and added two new records to the table relationships. Now I have two records user_one_id = 1 | user_two_id = 2 | status_id = 1 and the second one user_one_id = 1 | user_two_id = 3 | status_id = 1. After called method friends I got an empty result. Why? Because of this belongs to is incorrect because there is a join clause

Comment: try ```select * from "users" inner join "relationships" on "users"."id" = "relationships"."user_one_id" where status =3``` --- ```return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'relationships', 'id', 'user_one_id')->where(status,'=',3);```

Comment: You might also try defining the model of your relationship as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Comment: Do you understand that this join select * from "users" inner join "relationships" on "users"."id" = "relationships"."user_one_id" will try join two tables during current user ID and will return incorrect results?

Comment: recreated the problem in a fresh install, check the answer. @Viktor